# Regex to find string independently or attached with tags php

Tags: php, regex

I want to search for the regex that finds abc word from paragraph with following scenarios:

1. **abc**
2. **'abc'**
3. **"abc"**
4. **abc's**
5. **def'abc**
6. **`abc`**
7. **(abc)**
8. **[abc]**
9. **{abc}**
10. **abc`<br/>` (any tag can appear after abc)**
11. **`<br/>`abc (any tag can appear befor abc)**
12. **abc:**
13. **abc;**
14. **abc,**
15. **@abc (Here apart from @ it can be any special character)**

After finding all those abc i want to replace them with this:
`<span class='clsIgnoreWord'>abc</span>`.

Which will be regex for finding these scenarios and replacing those with the above mentioned span enclosure?

The code which i have tried was for only word replacement and i want all above scenarios in one regex....

The code which i tried was for single word is:

```
preg_replace(
    "/\b" . $string . "\b/",
    "<span  class='clsIgnoreWord'>" . $string . "</span>",
    $paragraphText
);
```

Comment: have you tried any code ? Could we see it please

Comment: Instead of posting the code as comments, please add that code in your post itself by editing it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$word = 'abc';
$subject = "here there def'abc";
$replacement = '<span class="clsIgnoreWord">abc</span>';
$pattern = "/([^\w^\ ^\>]|\<br\/?\>|(\w+\'?))?(" . preg_quote($word) . "(\'s)?)(\<br\/?\>|[^\w^\ ^\<])?/";

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

Regex explanation:

The first group `([^\w^\ ^\>]|\<br\/?\>|(\w+\'?))?` will match zero or:

- a single non-character other then space and `>`: `[[^\w^\ ^\>]]` part or
- a `<br>` or `<br/>` tag: `\<br\/?\>` or
- a group characters that are followed by `'` if there are any: `(\w+\'?)` part.

Second group `(" . preg_quote($word) . "(\'s)?)` will match anything that variable `$words` holds and the `$word` value followed by `'s`.  [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) will escape any special chars in `$word`.

The third group `(\<br\/?\>|[^\w^\ ^\<])?` will match zero or:

- a single non-character other then space and `<`: `[^\w^\ ^\<]` part;
- a `<br>` or `<br/>` tag: `\<br\/?\>` part;

Comment: Thanks...but here abc word will be dynamic...here in question i have used abc as the an example...abc will be $string that will be dynamic:See the question.

Comment: You want to match any word and word with `'s` instead of abc?

Comment: Yes...here the word to match will be dynamic. abc word is example word here...it will be any word and it will be php variable.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Here in the the case: abc<br/>....it replaces the '<' of <br/> with the replacement....what happens is : abc$replacementbr/>...the '<' should not be replaced by the replacement and it should be preserved.

Comment: You want to replace only `<br/>` tags or any other html tags that wrap the word?

Comment: I've edited the answer, does this solves your problem?

Comment: No...it still not...it replaces with the existing bracket of (abc) with the replacement and removes the bracket completely.....i want those exising brackets on their place ...it should only replace the abc with the replacement that is specified....and this is happening with the every 15 cases that are mentioned above.....

Comment: If you don't wont special characters (`{`, `(` ...) to be replaces get remove the regex part that matches these: `"/(\<br\/?\>|(\w+\'?))?(" . preg_quote($word) . "(\'s)?)(\<br\/?\>)?/"`

Comment: It also replaces abc's with abcs......and if it finds abcdef then it applies replacement inside the word and the replacement applies to the abc part of the abcdef string ....it also replaces abc in the abc-def...this not need to happen.....